# how can we set balloon tips in android google map?

Tags: android

i want to set balloon tips in android google map...
please tell me how can we set and display balloon tips ?

Answer (score 2):

found: http://codemagician.wordpress.com/2010/05/06/android-google-mapview-tutorial-done-right/

Comment: i am also using the sample code from that url.
here they show the alert window when "onTab()"
but i want to show the balloon tooltip for that pinpoint...

Comment: than create a 9.png drawable and place it above the pinpoint. not very hard to do...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example of map ballon tips:
http://deckjockey.blogspot.com/2010/01/android-baloon-display-on-map.html